# Google Place Details

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a list of restaurants with their gps coordinates in a Listvview. I want to display the individual restaurant details upon click, that is, the restaurant Photo(if available), the address, website and phone number. I can't find a good example of the Google places details that would point me in the right direction on how to do this. I see examples where it shows markers on a map, but I want the actual details like you get when you arrive to your destination while using google maps including a streetview pic of your final destination, something like that. I hope my question is clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to look [here](http://hrabosch.com/2016/06/12/google-places-api-javascript-library-create-autocomplete-input-and-work-with-returned-data-via-javascript/) on this post. I wrote it in JavaScript, but if you need to know how to get this informations, i hope it will help you.
If you are able to get place, then you are able to get all details (if they are provided). [Here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResponses) is example of response with details for place. So if you are able to get details, then you are able to get phone, address, rating, references, etc.